# Visual Studio Code won't launch on virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtual-machine

I installed VSC recently on my VM, but after typing `code` in the terminal nothing happened. Afterwards typed `code --verbose` and I saw the following warning:

`(code:16063): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:08:46.490: cannot open display:`

I have tried both of the following suggestions and neither has worked:

`$ export DISPLAY='IP:0.0'`

`X11Forwarding yes`

Comment: Does your VM have enough RAM? Also, which Operating System do you have? Looks like something Linux or Unix based but just to be safe, please add that.

Comment: It's Ubuntu. I hope this info helps. 
`
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G        302M         97G        1.0M         27G        124G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
`